# Update matching column with the selected top 1 column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables Role and Role_Imp. I need to fetch Name column's value from the 1st row of the Role table. After that I need to update Name's column value in Role_Imp table for the rows which has Names same as the selected name from the Role table.

I am using the following query, which is not working as its wrong.

```
UPDATE Role_Imp
SET Role_Imp.Name = 'Role Test Change'
FROM Role_Imp
INNER JOIN
Role ON Role_Imp.Name = SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM Role
```

How should I do this?

Comment: "from the 1st row of the Role table" - What does this mean?  How do you determine the 1st row?

Comment: Do you not have a key for these rows? It looks like you use Name as your relational column? What happens when somebody changes their name? If you can provide ddl and some sample data I can show you how to do this. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: I want to change Name column's value in Role_Imp table for the Name in 1st row of the Role table. Doesn't matter what that Name is. Role_Imp has all the rows of the Role table. I want to change Name for 1 of those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this should do it:

```
UPDATE Role_Imp
SET Name = 'Role Test Change'
WHERE Name = (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM Role)
```

Comment: This simple query worked. I don't know why I didn't try it. Thanks.